# How to detect duplicate messages in a kafka topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, azureservicebus, kafka-producer-api, apache-kafka-streams

Hi I have an architecture similar to the image shown below.

I have two kafka producer which will send messages to kafka topic with frequent duplicate messages.

Is there a way that I can handle the situation in a easy manner something like service bus topic.

Thank you for your help.

[image]

Comment: Your question is rather abstract... Do you mean, that a single producer is sending a single message multiple times? If yes, you could exploit "idempotend producer" that was added in Kafka 0.11.

Comment: No I have two different producers which will sometimes write same message to kafka topic.

Comment: @sap1ens gave a good answer for this case below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that you actually have *multiple different producers* writing the same messages, I can see these two options:

1) Write all duplicates to a single Kafka topic, then use something like Kafka Streams (or any other stream processor like Flink, Spark Streaming, etc.) to deduplicate the messages and write deduplicated results to a new topic.

Here's a great Kafka Streams example using state stores: https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/4.0.0-post/src/test/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/EventDeduplicationLambdaIntegrationTest.java

2) Make sure that duplicated messages have the same message key. After that you need to enable [log compaction](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#compaction) and Kafka will *eventually* get rid of the duplicates. This approach is less reliable, but if you tweak the compaction settings properly it might give you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Now, Apache Kafka supports exactly-once delivery: https://www.confluent.io/blog/exactly-once-semantics-are-possible-heres-how-apache-kafka-does-it/